# como sumar y restar la fecha y hora en Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

estoy realizando esto:

```
 String hora1='20:15:00';
 String hora2='00:10:00';     

 var horaTotal= new DateTime(DateTime.parse(hora1).hour + DateTime.parse(hora2).hour);
```

**espero de respuesta 20:25:00, pero me devuelve null**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para sumar `DateTime` lo puedes hacer con el método add que tiene esa clase, ahora primero debes definir bien tus fechas antes de sumarlas.

Revisa el constructor de la clase [DateTime](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) , lo tendrías que usar de esta manera :

```dart
DateTime fecha1 =  DateTime.parse('1969-07-20 20:15:00Z');
DateTime fecha2 =  DateTime.parse('1969-07-20 00:10:00Z');

 //o

//DateTime fecha1 =  DateTime(1969,07,20,20,15,0);
//DateTime fecha2 =  DateTime(1969,07,20,00,10,0);


DateTime horaTotal= fecha1.add(Duration(hours: fecha2.hour, minutes: fecha2.minute));
print(horaTotal);
print(horaTotal.hour); 
print(horaTotal.minute);
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas es más fácil tienes un método que te calcula la diferencias entre rango de fechas:

```
setState(() {
  Duration _diastotales = _endDate.difference(_startDate);
  print('${_diastotales.inDays}');
```